# ARP scan doesn't return waited result

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arp

I'm wondering why when I execute `arp-scan`, `netdiscover`, `nmap` or different ARP discover tools I don't get any result regarding my other NIC connected to the same computer.

```
wlan1: 192.168.0.10
wlan2: 192.168.0.11
```

If I execute `arp-scan --interface=wlan1 192.168.0.0/24` it only return:

```
 192.168.0.1 -> AB:CD:EF:01:23:45 which is the router (default gateway).
```

Is this behaviour correct? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARP will never resolve a locally connected NIC. The IP stack always routes packets destined for a locally connected IP adress internally, i.e. without sending them over any interface. There's simply no need to do it.

Comment: Is there any possible solution to change this behaviour?

Comment: Not that I know of. There's no need to discover local addresses via ARP because the stack is already aware of these.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm trying to start a MITM and I don't want to use 2 different laptops, but if there is not any solution I will do this.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, maybe a packet capturing tool à la Wireshark is a better approach.

Comment: Ok, I will follow your aproach. Thank you :)